# PL/SQL ORA-29280: invalid directory path and ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE" in oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I just want to write table data into a text file using `UTL_FILE` concept.What I've done is

i) Created a new directory:

```
  Create directory ddd as 'D:\sql';
```

ii) Granted Read and Write access of that directory to the user HR:

```
 grant read,write on directory ddd to hr;
```

iii) Granted misc UTL_FILE privileges:

```
 grant execute on UTL_FILE to hr;
```

I wrote the program  and got error as follows:

```
SQL> connect hr/admin

Connected.

SQL> declare      
  2   f  utl_file.file_type;      
  3  i  varchar(100);    
  4  begin    
  5  f:=utl_file.fopen('ddd','utlfile.txt','w',32767);    
  6  for x in(select first_name,salary from employees where rownum<=10)loop    
  7  i:=x.first_name||' '||x.salary;    
  8  utl_file.put_line(f,i);    
  9  utl_file.new_line(f);    
 10  end loop;    
 11  utl_file.fclose(f);    
 12  end;    
 13  /
```

**Got output as:**

```
declare    
*    
ERROR at line 1:    
ORA-29280: invalid directory path    
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41    
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478    
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

I don't know what am I missing here.... I'm struggling with this issue for around 2 days. Please help me..

Comment: Directory names are uppercased, try `DDD` instead of `ddd`

Answer (score 0):

The variable we used was defined was a `char` instead of a `varchar2`, so it was padding spaces into the file name.